# Getting specific object in nested JSON

Tags: json, angular

I have following JSON retrieved from Web service and I am able to get specific element in nested JSON by hard-coding the index in html. Below is the sample data. This is just a portion of entire JSON, I caught rest of them and they are all in same order.

Now, I would like to get "id" element in condition to Name. All names will be given, but index for Table where Names located are unknown. I need to be able to get "id" for all given names. How should proceed this?

```
{
    "School": {
        "Table": [
            {
                "Name": [ "Leo" ],
                "id": [ "123" ],
                "class": [ "A" ]
            },
            {
                "Name": [ "Kelvin" ],
                "id": [ "456" ],
                "class": [ "B" ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

```js
 ngOnInit(): void {
    this.appService.getData().subscribe(res =>
      this.results = res,
      error => console.log(error)
    );
 }
```

Comment: I am having a hard time with your language.  what do you mean by "id" element in condition to Name.  Are you saying that you want to get the id only if the name exists?

Comment: Yes, for all given Names.

Comment: At the end you want a list of the ids:  ["123","456"]?

Comment: Yes, in html...

Comment: Can you update your question to include what the desired html would look like in the end.

Comment: it'll be just a table that shows id only. I don't need to output names or anything.

Comment: your json is invalid...

Comment: please refer to edited

Comment: Please carefully learn the meaning of the word "JSON".

Comment: what's wrong?;;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's already been said but use a data service. Once that has returned the JSON data it's much easier to transform it to exactly how you want it. I've done a bit to this recently. Here's an example of a data service that does exactly this. Once `this.gearDataJSON = gearData;` is populated you can easily process the data into something the easy to work with on the HTML side.

**Component**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/Rx';

import { GearDataService } from '../../services/geardata.service'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-gears',
  templateUrl: './gears.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./gears.component.css']
})

@Injectable()

export class GearsComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public gearDataService : GearDataService) {}

  gearDataJSON;                                                                                    // Holds a complete copy of gears.json data
  manufacturerNames : string[];                                                                    // Bit of JSON that we want to chop off or process

  ngOnInit()
  {

    this.gearDataService.getGearData().subscribe((gearData) =>                                     // Load in gear data and populate array for control and selection
    {

      this.gearDataJSON = gearData;

      this.manufacturerNames = gearData.manufacturers;

     });

  }
```

**DataService**

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class GearDataService {
  constructor(public http : Http) {}

  getGearData()
  {
    return this.http.get("./assets/gears.json")
    .map(res => res.json());
  }

}
```

Comment: this is almost exactly what I have. What I need to do is, to point to Names then acquire Id's. Sasxa's answer is what I was looking for, but still having a problem to deploy like he mentioned

Answer (score 1):

This might be what you're looking for:

```
School.Table
  .filter(o => o.Name === 'condition')
  .map(o => o.id)
```

For example:

```
<p *ngFor="let id of ids$ |async"> {{ id }} </p>

this.ids$ = this.service.getSchool()
  .map((o: School) => o.Table
    .filter(o => o.Name === 'condition')
    .map(o => o.id))
```

Comment: should I include this in my service or where I am subscribing?

Comment: I'd suggest to keep data as is in your services, and do these kind of transformations in components (where you actually need specific values).

Comment: isn't this only working with a single name and an id? What should I do if i have multiples?

Comment: You can use custom filter function `myNameFilter(name) { return "true" when matches }`, and use it `.filter(o => myNameFilter(o.Name))`...

Comment: Hi Sasxa, I am having a problem for deploying those .map functions. I am subscribing in component and returns whole object as  **res**. Where should I include those map functions?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that your json was something like-

### component.ts

```
 school:any = {
      Table:[
         {
            name: "Steve",
            id:"123"            
         },
         {
            id:"456"
         }
      ]
   };
```

If you want the output html to look like you suggested you don't really need to match the name but can just use iteration.

### component.html

```
<table>
    <tr>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let user of school.Table">
         <td>{{user.name}}</td>
     </ng-container>
     </tr> 
    <tr>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let user of school.Table">
         <td>{{user.id}}</td>
     </ng-container>
     </tr> 
  </table>
```

Would that suffice?

Comment: i need to match with names?

Comment: I think I got wht you want.

Comment: not sure how this matches the name given.. for example, if i am looking id:123 in condition to Steve, how does it know whether it's Steve or some other name?

Comment: Do you want to know the ids for all students named Steve?

Comment: @Saxsa seems to understand what you want.

Comment: Names are unique for each ID's. Sorry, I think I made you confused again.

Comment: can i do this in this way?

Comment: Please update with an example of what you want the html to look like for final product.  it is still unclear to me what you are asking.

Comment: I updated my answer to make your result.  I don't think you need to match the name.

Comment: You don't understand the question. Not sure how much more I can make it clear. But thanks for help.